# class with pointer type member fails at destruction under MSVS2012@debug. Program error or bad source?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, pointers, destructor, assert

When I try to debug my big program with msvs2012, it always ends up with `_BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)` if I do it in debug mode. In Release mode and under g++ (with -O0 flag too) it gives no error. I also read some articles on this topic (the error message and pointers in classes and destructors) but I can't find what's wrong with my code. I provided a minimal (not)working example below. Can you point out what's wrong and show how to solve it? (Using std containers is not a solution for me.)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;    



class block_data {
public:
    int size;
    double * data;
    block_data() {};
    block_data(int s)
    {
        size = s;
        data = new double [size];
        for (int i=0; i<size; ++i)
            data[i] = i;
    }

    ~block_data() {delete[] data;};

    block_data operator+(const block_data& toadd)
    {
        block_data C(toadd.size);
        for (int i=0; i<size; ++i)
            C.data[i] = data[i] + toadd.data[i];

        return C;
    }

    block_data& operator=(const block_data& copy)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<size; ++i)
            data[i] += copy.data[i];
        return *this;
    }

};


int main()
{
    block_data sum(10);

    for (int seed = 0; seed < 10; ++seed)
    {       
        block_data d(10);
        sum = sum + d;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nearly any time you allocate memory in your const5ructor, you also need a copy constructor to properly handle copying it... You also need an `operator=`, but you seem to have that already.

Comment: That test is only performed in the Debug build you can't ever see this diagnostic in a Release build.  The test is 100% accurate, you really *do* have a pointer bug in your code.  Caused by the missing copy constructor that's used by operator+().  With the wee corner case that this specific bug doesn't byte in the optimized build because it can optimize the copy constructor call away.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like if I add a copy constructor, it solves the problem as @Dark Falcon suggested.

```
block_data(block_data& tocopy) : size(tocopy.size), data(new double[tocopy.size])
{
    for (int i=0; i<size; ++i)
        data[i] = tocopy.data[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the copy constructor issue already mentioned, you will have an access violation in your operator+ if toadd.size is smaller than size since you will be referencing unallocated memory, same goes for the assignment operator.